# Trouble with SQL Server locks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running into an issue where SQL Server is causing a significant number of locks (95 to 150) on our main table.  They are typically short duration locks, lasting under 3 seconds, but I would like to eliminate those if I possibly can.  We have also noticed that typically there are no blocks, but occasionally we have a situation where the blocks seem to "cascade" and then the entire system slows down considerably.

**Background**

We have up to 600 virtual machines processing data and we loaded a table in SQL so we could monitor any records that got stalled and records that were marked complete.  We typically have between 200,000 and 1,000,000 records in this table during our processing.

**What we are trying to accomplish**

We are attempting to get the next available record (Status = 0).  However, since there can be multiple hits on the stored proc simultaneously, we are trying to make sure each VM gets a unique record.  This is important because processing takes between 1.5 and 2.5 minutes per record and we want to make this as clean as possible.

**Our thought process to this point**

```
UPDATE TOP (1) dbo.Test WITH (ROWLOCK)
SET Status = 1, 
    VMID = @VMID, 
    ReadCount = ReadCount + 1,
    ProcessDT = GETUTCDATE()
OUTPUT INSERTED.RowID INTO @retValue
WHERE Status = 0
```

This update was causing us a few issues with locks, so we re-worked the process a little bit and changed the where to a sub-query to return the top 1 RowID (primary key) from the table.  This seemed to help things run a little bit smoother, but then we occasionally get over-loaded in the database again.

```
UPDATE TOP (1) dbo.Test WITH (ROWLOCK)
SET Status = 1, 
    VMID = @VMID, 
    ReadCount = ReadCount + 1,
    ProcessDT = GETUTCDATE()
OUTPUT INSERTED.RowID INTO @retValue
-- WHERE Status = 0
WHERE RowID IN (SELECT TOP 1 RowID FROM do.Test WHERE Status = 0 ORDER BY RowID)
```

We discovered that having a significant number of Status 1 and 2 records int he table causes slowdowns.  We figured it was from a table scan on the Status column.  We added the following index but it did not help solve the locks.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Test_Status_RowID
ON [dbo].[Test] ([Status])
INCLUDE ([RowID])
```

The final step after the UPDATE, we use the RowID returned to select out the details:

```
SELECT 'Test' as FileName, *, @Nick as [Nickname] 
FROM Test WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE RowID IN (SELECT id from @retValue)
```

**Types of locks**

The majority of the blocks are LCK_M_U and LCK_M_S, which I would expect with that UPDATE and SELECT query.  We did have 1 or 2 LCK_M_X locks as well occasionally.  That made me think we may still be getting collisions on our "unique" record code.

**Questions**

1. Are these locks and the number of locks just normal SQL operations for this type load?
2. Is the sub-query causing more issues than a TOP(1) in the UPDATE we started with?  I am trying to get confirmation I can remove the ORDER BY statement and remove that extra step of processing.
3. Would a different index help?  I wondered if the index updating was a possible cause of the locks initially, but now I am not sure.
4. Is there a better or more efficient way to get a unique RowID?
5. Is the WITH (ROWLOCK) causing more locks than leaving it off would cause?  The idea is ROWLOCK would only lock the 1 specific record and allow another proc to update another record and select without locking the table or page.
6. Does anyone have any tools they recommend to stress test and run 100 queries simultaneously in order to test any potential solutions?

Sorry for all the questions, just  trying to make sure I am as clear as possible on our process and the questions we have.

Thanks in advance for any insight as this is a really frustrating issue for us.

**Hardware**

We are running SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Dual Xeon CPU with 24 GB of RAM.  So we should have plenty of horsepower for this process.

Comment: Seems that you're trying to do a simple producent - consumer. Have you think of using some message queue, like MSMQ or RabbitMQ? Implementation of these processes are quite complex.

Comment: For the load testing, you could try SQL Query Stress by Adam Machanic http://www.datamanipulation.net/sqlquerystress/

Comment: It might be useful to check statistics IO output for the different update options, that should help solving what's the best query

Comment: You should probably have a good reason, but I just wanted to know why you don't use an IDENTITY column to get a unique Id ?

Comment: Hi Rubik - The RowID is an identity column and Primary Key.  That's why the sub-query returns the RowID for quicker updates and final select out of the table.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, JameZ.  I will give those a try and see what my testing reveals.  I'm an app developer and this level of DB work is a bit over my head.

Comment: JamesZ: Thanks for the Statistics IO hint.  I was able to verify my logical reads dropped from 4500 to 10 with the use of the index.  So the index stays.  I also verified the sub-query method is more efficient with the index than the update TOP (1) ... where Status = 0.  However, during stress testing 100 threads, the blocks returned.  I figured out what Rubik meant and created a second table to return the ID from an insert instead of scanning the existing table.  That seems to have stopped the locks, but now I have to figure out a way to re-run any that are stalled.  Progress!  Thanks guys!

Comment: One more thing to try.  When you are trying to target a fairly unique set of values for a column, like in your case for status, you can create a [filtered index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372(v=sql.105).aspx).  In your case, the filter would be status = 0.  This will increase your chances of using that index and a lot less reads getting to it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best solution to the issue was to create a separate table with an identity and use the `@@IDENTITY` from the insert to determine the next row to process. That has solved all my lock issues so far in my stress testing. Thanks to all who pointed my in the right direction!